# Recebendo System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage<TModel>.Model.get retornou null

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Estou recebendo um erro de referência nula e não entendo por que. Segue o erro:

```
System.NullReferenceException: 'Referência de objeto não definida para uma instância de um objeto.'

System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage<TModel>.Model.get retornou null.
```

[Debuguei](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L7RLL.jpg) onde faço as atribuições de valores para as variáveis onde está dando [referência nula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bM821.jpg).

Deu um [quick watch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ux5AZ.jpg) e vi que está recebendo sim os meus valores.

Segue o código de onde acontece o erro:

```
@model Application.ViewModels.ProdutoViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

<h2>Create</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Produto</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Descricao, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Descricao, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Descricao, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Categoria, "Categoria", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                // acontece o erro nessa linha. Qualquer coisa coloquei o 
                // print do erro em um link lá em cima
                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CategoriaId,
               new SelectList(Model.Categorias, "CategoriaId", "CategoriaNome"), new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CategoriaId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.SubCategoria, "SubCategoria", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SubCategoriaId,
                new SelectList(Model.SubCategorias, "SubCategoriaId", "SubCategoriaNome"), new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SubCategoriaId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.UnidadeMedida, "Unidade de Medida", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.UndMedidaId,
                new SelectList(Model.UnidadeMedidas, "UndMedidaId", "UndMedidaNome"), new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UndMedidaId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Criar" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Voltar", "Index")
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

Método do *controller* de Produto

```
// GET: Produtos/Create
        public ActionResult Create()
        {
            _produtoViewModel = new ProdutoViewModel();
            _produtoViewModel.Categorias = _categoriaAppService.ObterTodas();
            _produtoViewModel.SubCategorias = _subCategoriaAppService.ObterTodas();
            _produtoViewModel.UnidadeMedidas = _undMedidaAppService.ObterTodas();

            return View();
        }
```

Pilha

```
System.NullReferenceException ocorrido

      HResult=0x80004003
      Message=Referência de objeto não definida para uma instância de um objeto.
      Source=App_Web_5yz4eaco
      StackTrace:
       em ASP._Page_Views_Produtos_Create_cshtml.Execute() em c:\Users\iagof\Source\Workspaces\Views\Produtos\Create.cshtml:linha 28
       em System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy()
       em System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy()
       em System.Web.WebPages.StartPage.RunPage()
       em System.Web.WebPages.StartPage.ExecutePageHierarchy()
       em System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage)
       em System.Web.Mvc.RazorView.RenderView(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer, Object instance)
       em System.Web.Mvc.BuildManagerCompiledView.Render(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer)
       em System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
       em System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResult(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult)
       em System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult)
       em System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult)
```

Comment: Man, você está tentando pegar uma lista de um objeto que não foi passado para view. Não seria melhor você fazer uma `ViewBag` com suas listas e usar no seu DropDown?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Falta passar o model pra view.

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
    _produtoViewModel = new ProdutoViewModel();
    _produtoViewModel.Categorias = _categoriaAppService.ObterTodas();
    _produtoViewModel.SubCategorias = _subCategoriaAppService.ObterTodas();
    _produtoViewModel.UnidadeMedidas = _undMedidaAppService.ObterTodas();

    return View(_produtoViewModel);
}
```

Comment: Putz! Deu certo aqui. Falta de atenção minha. Obrigado!